# Extract Values from a Matrix with condition z<x<y

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements, extract

My aim is to extract certain values from a matrix with an operator like this one: `z<x<y`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

From these matrix a want to extract values which are lower than 3 and higher than 6. I would be very thankful if anybody would help me.

Comment: `which(z<3)` & `which(z>6)` will give you a good start.

Comment: The given matrix does not contain any number which is lower than 3 and higher than 6 simultaneously. Actually i doubt such a matrix ever exists :)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser  What are you taking about?

Comment: @Pascal I've read the question 3 times. It seems to be about numbers which are `6<x<3`

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser  No, it is x<3 or x>6.

Comment: @Pascal well what `z<x<y` in the question stands for?

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser  I don't know. OP's mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
z <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, byrow = TRUE) 
z[z < 3 | z > 6]
# [1] 1 7 2 8 9
```

Sorted:

```
sort(z[z < 3 | z > 6])
# [1] 1 2 7 8 9
```

Comment: No my answer is wrong @Pascal. It gives the position. I will delete it.

Comment: @PAscal, try this: `z<-matrix(7:15, nrow=3, ncol=3)`

Comment: @Pascal, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Pascal for -  `z<-matrix(7:15, nrow=3, ncol=3)` , the statement - `which(z>6)`, gives the output
`[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and the statement `z[z > 6]` gives the output `[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15`. Makes sense now?

Comment: `z[which(z>6)]`. Anyway, your answer is correct. And for clarification, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @HansDampf  If the answer is useful, please consider to accept it.